# split up a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that I need to plit into chunks with 10 records each. 
I've tried using array_chunk, but using that, I loose the `[catalogue_detail]` and `[catalogue_print_lines]` keys that are used in my views.

The original array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [catalogue_detail] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 140
                    [catalogue_name] => robintestbig
                    [creation_date] => 2017-05-23
                )
        )
    [catalogue_print_lines] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4902
                    [catalogue_id] => 140
                    [product_id] => 5551
                    [theimage] => 10c96-pc9802m-paa.jpg
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4903
                    [catalogue_id] => 140
                    [product_id] => 6758
                    [theimage] => 50b8f-pc9802m-snb.jpg
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4904
                    [catalogue_id] => 140
                    [product_id] => 6760
                    [theimage] => b2592-pc9802m-snd.jpg
                )
            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4905
                    [catalogue_id] => 140
                    [product_id] => 7321
                    [theimage] => ae175-pc9910-bwc.jpg
                )
        )
)
```

I need an output like the one below

```
array 
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [catalogue_detail] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 140
                            [catalogue_name] => robintestbig
                            [creation_date] => 2017-05-23
                        )
                )
            [catalogue_print_lines] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 4902
                            [catalogue_id] => 140
                            [product_id] => 5551
                            [theimage] => 10c96-pc9802m-paa.jpg
                        )
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 4903
                            [catalogue_id] => 140
                            [product_id] => 6758
                            [theimage] => 50b8f-pc9802m-snb.jpg
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [catalogue_detail] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 140
                            [catalogue_name] => robintestbig
                            [creation_date] => 2017-05-23
                        )
                )
            [catalogue_print_lines] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 4902
                            [catalogue_id] => 140
                            [product_id] => 5551
                            [theimage] => 10c96-pc9802m-paa.jpg
                        )
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 4903
                            [catalogue_id] => 140
                            [product_id] => 6758
                            [theimage] => 50b8f-pc9802m-snb.jpg
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Current I'm using it as follows:

```
$datachunks = array_chunk($datamain, 10);
foreach ($datachunks as $data) {
  ...#code
}
```

The resulting array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 140
                    [catalogue_name] => robintestbig
                    [creation_date] => 2017-05-23
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4902
                    [catalogue_id] => 140
                    [product_id] => 5551
                    [theimage] => 10c96-pc9802m-paa.jpg
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4903
                    [catalogue_id] => 140
                    [product_id] => 6758
                    [theimage] => 50b8f-pc9802m-snb.jpg
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4904
                    [catalogue_id] => 140
                    [product_id] => 6760
                    [theimage] => b2592-pc9802m-snd.jpg
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4905
                    [catalogue_id] => 140
                    [product_id] => 7321
                    [theimage] => ae175-pc9910-bwc.jpg
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4906
                    [catalogue_id] => 140
                    [product_id] => 7425
                    [theimage] => 95353-ru02-bha.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: You need to split subarrays, not arrays.

Comment: Your example _I need an output like the one below_ does not seem to split the array into parts with 10 records each

Comment: Did it ever occur to you, you left out the important part? `...#code`. What you say doesn't match with what you display, so this code could help a lot.

Comment: how are you creating the initial array? maybe you don't need to use `array_chunk` at all, while on the fetching (if this comes from a db select) just add the `catalogue_detail` then just use a counter and modulus to `10` and put that batch, and the next batch, instead of creating an array, then creating another chunked one

Comment: @Ghost I am getting the catalogue_detail from a select, yes. I'm trying it that way now.